# How to Setup an ANT file to create a JAVA JAR that is containing/packaging this calculator?

Tags: ant, junit, jar, intellij-idea

I already made a running program which is calculator in IntelliJ IDEA and make a test and it goes fine. My problem is that how to setup an ANT file to create a JAVA JAR that is calculator.

Hoping for your answers..

tnx.

Comment: Is there some files or code? Maybe a link to the code? What do you expect us to do? Have you read the Ant manual? I can't even write you an Ant script for you, let alone help you produce one because I have absolutely no information.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of an ant target that does jar creation.

```
<!-- roll up everyting into a single jar file -->
<target name="dist" depends="clean, compile" description="Generate the distribution file.">
<!--
Copy the library .jars to the directory where the distribution will be located
-->
<copy todir="${dist}">
<fileset dir="${lib}"/>
</copy>
<!-- TODO: Generate the MANIFEST.MF file on the fly -->
<jar jarfile="${dist}/myCalculator.jar" basedir="${build}" manifest="tools/MANIFEST.MF"/>
<!-- dump to web server -->
<copy todir="${web-files}">
<fileset dir="${dist}"/>
</copy>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Ant manual page for the Jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html). There are lots of examples there.